# the proper ideal of a quotient ring of a Dedekind domain $ / ^{n+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand what it says in the hint of EXERCIZE 5 in the 23p of this [pdf](https://www.cimat.mx/~luis/seminarios/Teoria-de-Numeros/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf).
For example, $\mathcal O = \mathbb Z$ and $\mathcal a = (4)$.
$\mathbb Z/(4) = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z = \{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$
and $a = (4) = \{ 4n | n \in \mathbb Z\} = \{ 2a \times 2b | 2a,2b \in (2)\} = (2)^2$.
So the proper ideal of $\mathbb Z/(4)$ is $(2)/(4)$.
What is $(2)/(4)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(2)/(4)$ is a quotient of abelian groups as well as $O$-modules

(ie. there is a natural $O$-action on the quotient group which is for $c\in (2),c+(4)\in (2)/(4),n\in O$, $n.(c+(4)) = nc+(4)$)

as well as an ideal of the quotient ring $O/(4)$

(so $(2)/(4)$ is also a $O/(4)$ module)